# Power BI slicer dropdown with array values

Tags: arrays, powerbi, dropdown, multi-select, slicers

I want to create a slicer for availableDataTypes field. I have array of values in availableDataTypes field.In the dropdown I want only [1],[2],[3] & none Options
It should be a multiselect dropdown.
If I select [1] in dropdown it should show me result of rows with availableDataTypes [1].
If I select [1] and [2] in dropdown it should show me result of rows with availableDataTypes [1],[2] [2,1]and [1,2].
If I select [1] [2] and [3] in dropdown it should show me result of rows with availableDataTypes [1],[2],[3] and [1,2,3] etc.

Im A beginner I tried to do it using functions in dax but didnt got it.[IMAGE FOR REFERENCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyjco.png)

Answer (score 0):

To handle situations like this, it is a common practice to create a bridge table. This requires some work in power query to build a relationship from the bridge table to the main table.

Here's a solutions .pbix file you can look at and study. Take a look in Power Query how the table was built/columns pivoted.
https://github.com/dataDad/stackOverflowSolutions/blob/main/stackOverflowBridgeTable.pbix
[image]

Comment: the eid in my table is unique so i cannot pivote/unpivote the columns as it will create duplicates can this be achieved without pivoting

Comment: you can pivot/unpivot with unique columns. Check the solution file.